# alternativ Bitmap class?

Tags: c#, bitmap

is there any alternative bitmap class, where `PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale`, or something like this, is working?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread seems to have a couple of suggestions](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/270353-format16bppgrayscale-not-supported) I haven't tried them.